# Could not load content for http://localhost:8000/js/pusher.js.map

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, phpwebsocket, laravel-websockets

console error :

```
"DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:8000/js/pusher.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"
```

i got error like this when i use pusher for my `laravel` app `websocket`, event successfully sent, but failed for listen, no listen anything. is there any solution for me?

(i am sorry for bad english)

Comment: This error is not an issue, you can ignore it. Problem is another place.